# Getting error message when trying send request to server using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have this code where im trying to create a dynamic route (localhost:3000/{ dynamicId}/userPage for each user but axios is returning me an error:

App.jsx

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import reactLogo from './assets/react.svg'
import './App.css'
import LoginPage from "./pages/LoginPage"
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import HomePage from './pages/HomePage';
import SignUpPage from './pages/SignUpPage'
import UserPage from './pages/UserPage';
function App() {
  

  return (
    <>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage/>}/>
      <Route path="login" element={<LoginPage/>}/>
      <Route path="signup" element={<SignUpPage/>}/>
      {/* <Route path="userpage" element={<UserPage/>}/> */}
      <Route path=":user/userpage" element={<UserPage />} />


      

    </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
    
      
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

UserPage.jsx

```
import axios from "axios"
import Button from "../Shared/FormElement/Button"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function UserPage(props) {
   const[isLoading,setIsLoading]=useState(false)
   const[isLoggedin, setIsLoggedin]=useState(false)
const handleLoad=(event)=>{
//-----------------------------PROBLEM-----------------------------------  
   setIsLoading(true)
       axios({
         method: "get",
         url: "api/dashboard",
       })
       .then((response) => {
       console.log("UserLoggedin:",response.data)
       setIsLoading(false)
       setIsLoggedin(true)
       if (!response.data)
           {navigate("/login")
       }
      
   })
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------  
}
   const navigate = useNavigate();
   useEffect(() => {
   //     // Code to run when the component mounts (page loads)
   //     // Add your event listener here
   //     window.addEventListener('load', handleLoad);
   
   //     // Code to clean up the event listener when the component unmounts (page unloads)
   //     return () => {
   //       window.removeEventListener('load', handleLoad);
   //     };
   console.log("being called")
   handleLoad()
     }, []);
function handleclick(event){
   axios(
       {
           method: "post",
           url: "api/logout"
       }
   ).then((response) => {
       console.log(response.data)
       if (!response.data)
           navigate("/login")
   })
}
   
   return isLoggedin&&<div>
       <h1>Hello User</h1>
       <Button type="submit" style="primary" onClick={handleclick}> Logout</Button>
       {isLoading &&<h2>Loading...</h2>}
       
   </div>

}
export default UserPage
```

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
 plugins: [react()],
 server: {
   proxy: {
     '/api': {
       target: 'http://localhost:3000',
       changeOrigin: true,
       rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, '')
     }
   }
 }
})
```

In my server

```
require('dotenv').config()
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const express = require("express")
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const session = require('express-session');
const saltRounds = 10;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors())
PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
}))

app.use(passport.initialize())

app.use(passport.session())



const authUser = (email, password, done) => {
    Account.findOne({ Email: email }).exec()
        .then((account) => {
            if (account) {
                bcrypt.compare(password, account.Password).then(function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        done(null, { account }, { message: "Succesfull" })

                    }
                    else {
                        // console.log("Check  password again",)      
                        done(null, false, { message: "Invalid password" })

                    }
                })
            }
            else {
                // console.log("Check your email ",)
                done(null, false, { message: "Invalid password" })
            }

        })
        .catch((error) => done(error));

    ;


}
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',    // define the parameter in req.body that passport can use as username and password
    passwordField: 'password'
},authUser))
passport.serializeUser((userObj, done) => {
    done(null, userObj.account.id); // Store only the user ID in the session
  });
  
  passport.deserializeUser((userId, done) => {
    Account.findOne({ id: userId })
      .exec()
      .then((account) => {
        done(null, { account });
      })
      .catch((error) => done(error));
  });


const { Schema, model } = mongoose;
const MongooseConnect = async () => {
    try {
        const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODBBKEY);
        console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        process.exit(1)
    }


}
const user_accounts = new Schema({
    id:String,
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    Email: String,
    Password: String
})
const Account = model("Account", user_accounts)

app.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local", (err, user, info) => {
    if (user) {
      req.logIn(user, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        console.log(user, info);
        console.log(req.isAuthenticated());
        console.log(user.account.id);
        return res.json({
          id: user.account.id,
          authentication: true,
        });
      });
    } else {
      console.log(user, info);
      // Authentication failed
      return res.json({
        id: user.account.id,
        authentication: false,
      });
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
//-----------------------------PROBLEM-----------------------------------    
  app.get("/dashboard",(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log(req.isAuthenticated())
    res.json(req.isAuthenticated())
//----------------------------------------------------------------    
  })
  app.post('/logout', function(req, res, next){
    req.logout(function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      console.log(req.isAuthenticated())
      res.json(req.isAuthenticated())
    });
  });



app.post("/signup", async (req, res, next) => {
    Account.findOne({ Email: req.body.Email }).exec()
        .then((account) => {
            if (!account) {
                bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, saltRounds).then(function (hash) {
                    const user = Account({
                        id:uuidv4(),
                        first_name: req.body.first_name,
                        last_name: req.body.lastname,
                        Email: req.body.Email,
                        Password: hash,
                    })
                    user.save()
                });

                console.log("User Created");
                const Accountexist = false
                res.json(Accountexist)
            }
            else {
                console.log("Account Exist")
                const Accountexist = true
                res.json(Accountexist)
            }

        })



})


MongooseConnect().then
    (app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`Working in port ${PORT}`)
    }))
    
  })
```

I'm getting this error:

[image: ErrorMessage]

The id is generated through UUID that im setting as the dynamic parameter/routing. Why is it saying that there is no route with dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a leading slash to your URL in the axios call:

```
axios({
  method: "get",
  url: "/api/dashboard",
})
```

You can see in the log that the requested URL was: `http://localhost:5173/{SOME-ID}/api/dashboard`, when you make a request client-side with `axios` without a leading slash, the browser (or axios?) assumes you are trying to request some endpoint staring from the current page instead of an absolute path.

You will want to do the same for the `api/logout` request, which is also without a leading slash.